# pass parameter to construct of an angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

279/5000
I have a constructor that inherits from another constructor
but when I define an any parameter in the constructor, I get an error, I want to inherit from the parent component, but pass different types of services, for this reason in the parent constructor I define, that it receives an any parameter

Constructor son
[image: constructor hijo]

Constructor base
[image]

Comment: `I get an error` <= You neglected to include the error message / text in your question. Please [edit] your question and add it (copy it as text, no screenshots please).

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't extends components.
As your logic is in your services, you should just rely on them.

Comment: I want to receive an any parameter in the parent constructor